# powershell.exe does not honor -nologo when the script of -file does not exist

Tags: powershell

everything is in the title.

```
C:\> powershell -exec bypass -nologo -noprofile -file .\myscript.ps1
<script output>
```

while

```
C:\> powershell -exec bypass -nologo -noprofile -file .\invalid.ps1
The argument '.\invalid.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows
```

did I miss something? is there a way to just get the error without the *logo*?

```
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.3031
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.3031
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

### edit

the command line `powershell ...` is executed from CMD, not from powershell.

Comment: is it necessary to start a new process of powershell from powershell to execute the script? why do you not directly invoke the script from the shell: & .\myscript.ps1?

Comment: @Toni this is a CMD command line, not a powershell one.

Comment: you might redirect the stderr to a file: powershell -exec bypass -nologo -noprofile -file .\myscript.ps1 2> C:\err.txt

Comment: Like @Toni said redirect the error output to a file, parse the output to remove the logo, and then display or log the modified output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `-NoLogo` isn't honored in this scenario is certainly a bug.

- It affects [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, only.
- While [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, no longer has the *same* problem, it also produces additional output that may be unwanted, namely *usage information* (command-line help).

There is no good workaround for `-File`, unfortunately.

You can switch to `-Command`-based invocation (where `-nologo` isn't even necessary), but you'll get a noisier error message:

```bash
powershell -exec bypass -noprofile -command .\myscript.ps1
```

However, note that using `-Command`:

- changes the syntax rules, because whatever argument(s) follow `-Command` are interpreted *as PowerShell code*, which notably means that if your script path contained *spaces* you'd have to invoke it as:

  ```bash
  powershell -exec bypass -noprofile -command "& '.\my script.ps1'"
  ```
- only reports an *abstract* exit code (`0` for success, `1` for all errors); you could (awkwardly) compensate for that as follows.

  ```bash
  powershell -exec bypass -noprofile -command ".\myscript.ps1; exit $(if ($LASTEXITCODE) { $LASTEXITCODE } elseif (-not $?) { -196608 })"
  ```

  - `-196608` is the exit code `powershell.exe` uses to signal a nonexistent file when `-File` is used; `pwsh.exe` uses `64`

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac: I had to amend [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1827069/139307): while the effective behavior was described correctly, the explanation wasn't quite correct with respect to modules.